# Curl has incorrect DNS resolution in a dind context

Tags: domain-name-system, docker, curl

I am running a `docker:20.10.7-dind` container.

Into this one I am running a multi containers app.

One container is a `back` container. Another one is a `keycloak` container.

I connect on the `back` container and have :

```
back$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

```
back$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts: files dns
```

```
back$ nslookup keycloak.localhost
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   keycloak.localhost
Address: 172.20.0.10

back$ host keycloak.localhost
keycloak.localhost has address 172.20.0.10
```

```
back$ nc keycloak.localhost 443 -vvv
keycloak.localhost (172.20.0.10:443) open
```

However, when it comes to curl :

```
back$ curl https://keycloak.localhost -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:443...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 443 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying [::1]:443...
* Immediate connect fail for ::1: Address not available
* Failed to connect to keycloak.localhost port 443 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to keycloak.localhost port 443 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

I notice that curl badly resolve the `keycloak.localhost` but I cannot figure out why ?

Note that if I help curl to resolve, it works like a charm :

```
back$ curl https://keycloak.localhost -v --resolve keycloak.localhost:443:172.20.0.10
* Added keycloak.localhost:443:172.20.0.10 to DNS cache
* Hostname keycloak.localhost was found in DNS cache
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 172.20.0.10:443...
* Connected to keycloak.localhost (172.20.0.10) port 443 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: keycloak.localhost
> user-agent: curl/8.0.1
> accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/2 200 
...
```

I would appreciate any clue to help me understand this.

Cheers

Comment: What do you have in `/etc/hosts`? `nslookup` (but you should use `dig` instead) is a pure DNS client so it doesn't care about `/etc/hosts` and just ask some nameserver. On the contrary, `curl` asks the OS to do the name resolution by default, and in turn the OS can take various sources to resolve name. `files` is first in `/etc/resolv.conf` so the content of `/etc/hosts` will have priority over DNS queries for a given name.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek


```
back$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.18.0.1 keycloak.localhost
192.168.48.8 90c46daa0d2b
```

I have an explicit resolution in `/etc/hosts` because I have an extra host in my docker config `keycloak.localhost:host-gateway`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally figured it out.

It is due to the curl/libcurl version.

Since v7.85, curl is *always* resolving localhost to 127.0.0.1.

See :

https://curl.se/changes.html#7_85_0

https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/9192

I downgraded curl and my stuff is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get this to work is to append docker-compose network name as the last TLD on top of the configured network name e.g. `keycloak.localhost` fails but `keycloak.localhost.myfolder_default` will resolve.

To elaborate:

With this folder structure:

```
myfolder
└── docker-compose.yml
```

And this docker compose:

```
services:
  backend:
    image: backend:latest
    container_name: backend.localhost

  keycloak:
    image: keycloak:latest
    container_name: keycloak.localhost
```

The backend container will be able to resolve keycloak.localhost using any  tools that read /etc/resolv.conf properly (you can check if the tool opens the /etc/resolv.conf file by running it with `strace`). Any of these tools will work:

- `wget http://keycloak.localhost:8443`
- `getent hosts keycloak.localhost`
- `nslookup keycloak.localhost`
- `nc keycloak.localhost 8443 -v`

But in my case `netcat` showed the problem:

```
# nc keycloak.localhost 8443 -v
DNS fwd/rev mismatch: keycloak.localhost != keycloak.localhost.myfolder_default
keycloak.localhost [10.201.1.4] 8443 (?) open
```

Using the FQND finally worked correctly with libcurl:

`curl http://keycloak.localhost.myfolder_default:8443`

I was able to leave the names of my containers as-is because they resolve fine for 90% of programs that respect /etc/resolv.conf and use libc resolver. For programs using libcurl I started appending the `.myfolder_default` TLD to all URLs.

For the record I was using debian, curl version 7.88.1 with following nsswitch configs:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:          files dns
networks:       files
```